# Survive a fall from a helicopter with superpowers

Tags: super-powers

There is someone in a helicopter flying above a city. His name is Arthur. Arthur flies around 1,2 kilometers above the city. His Helicopter is about to get hit with a missile. Arthur jumps out of the helicopter. He wants to survive the fall. There is no water near. Only buildings. However he wants to get to the ground.

Here is a description of Arthur's power:

1. When he touches something he can set it on fire. (limit is the a building)
2. When he touches something he can turn it into fire. This means it's pure flames for a second. After that the object disappears. (because fire disappears when there is no fuel). He can turn large objects into flames but he has a limit. He can't touch the ground and turn that into fire. The Largest thing he can turn into fire is a skyscraper.
3. He is immune to fire
4. He has two swords he can use.

So how would he survive a fall?

Comment: I'm voting to put it on hold because it looks like *"You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world."* Please see [tour] and [help].

Comment: At first reading I assumed the helicopter would have superpowers. I am disappointed...

Comment: As opposite to common believe you have more chances of surviving by not landing in water. There are people who survived free fall from a flying airplane, none of them landed in water. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juliane_Koepcke

Comment: I know, but there might be people saying "look for water, which is not a option".

Comment: do you really expect the only answer you get after 1 hour is the best answer you can get?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T [A man with a wooden leg named Smith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9TrMNpUZM8)

Comment: I can't help it. What's the name of his other leg?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Coming from sufficient height (or rather, with sufficient speed), water is approximately equal to concrete.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling MythBusters disproved that.  It would still hurt, though... A lot.

Comment: @RonJohn *" It would still hurt, though... A lot."* Hence "approximately".

Comment: Even if he survives the fall, won't he be pummelled by all the helicopter wreckage falling a few seconds above him?

Comment: From your question: "There is someone in a helicopter flying above a city." And "The Largest thing he can turn into fire is a skyscraper." sounds like you have your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer I'm going to assume that "turning something into fire" is effectively the same as burning its whole mass in a very short time (i.e. making it explode).

So Arthur has a very handy way to stop his fall:

He could wait until he is close above ground and set his sword(s) ablast. He should be at terminal velocity at this point in time witch according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Examples) is at about 53m/s. If he has any kind of control over his explosive powers, he should try to slow the explosion down a little to create a maximum of about 5g in order to minimise the risk of [blacking out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Human_tolerance).

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most realistic solution, and it doesn't make use of his fire powers, but if you're going for Rule of Cool, you could have Arthur use the good old Blade Brake technique:

1. Arthur steers himself close to the nearest tall skyscraper.
2. Arthur thrusts both his swords deep into the side of said skyscraper.
3. The friction caused by the blades as they slice through the side of the skyscraper will gradually slow Arthur down to a stop - for maximum dramatic/stylistic effect, have him stop just a few feet above the ground.

In real-life, this wouldn't work: swords can't cut through skyscrapers, and even if they could, the initial jolt would probably rip Arthur's arms out of his sockets. But considering he can incinerate entire skyscrapers with a single touch, I dare say you're probably not too concerned about realism.